# DB-API SQLite INSERT statement throws InterfaceError in Python 2.7

Tags: python, sqlite

Given a SQLite table I've created, with the field in question being type `TEXT`, the following fails:
`hsh = hashlib.sha1("".join(some_list)).hexdigest()

db_setup(hsh)`
I receive the error:
`InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.`

```
def db_setup(my_hash, oavals)
    to_insert = (my_hash,)
    ('INSERT INTO position VALUES \
    (null, ?, ?, null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',(0, 0, to_insert,
    oavals["a"], oavals["b"],
    oavals["c"], oavals["d"]))
```

If I substitute a manual int or string (e.g. `57`, or `"hello"` for `to_insert` in the `db_setup` def, it works fine, which leads me to believe that it's tripping over the hash, for some reason. I feel as if I'm missing something obvious here.

---

Table schema:
    `'CREATE TABLE position \

    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, position INTEGER, displayline INTEGER, \

    header TEXT, digest TEXT, conkey TEXT, consecret TEXT, \

    acckey TEXT, accsecret TEXT)'`

Comment: What is the schema for the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing because `to_insert` is a tuple, not the value you wish to insert.

Try changing that first line to:

```
to_insert = my_hash
```

Or better yet, just put `my_hash` into your parameter list.

Here's an example:

```
>>> hsh = '49cb6536afc7e4a4b3a94eb493aae4d52b8f6a60'
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("CREATE TABLE t (i TEXT);")
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES (?)", (hsh,)) # tuple works
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x011A35E0>
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES (?)", ((123,),)) # tuple within tuple doesn't
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. The tuple-within-tuple was the problem. Thanks!